# Vapor - Server Side Swift: Doesn't find css

Tags: css, vapor

I have created a test Vapor web app, but it does not seem to serve the css files.
Do I have to do anything other than put them in the Public/styles directory (and rebuild) ?

Please see attached pic (note the css files in red).

[image]

Comment: Where is your HTML file being served from? Prefixing the stylesheet urls with `/` will make it an absolute path (`e.g http://0.0.0.0/styles/...`). If you want it relative to the HTML file, use `styles/...` instead.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding with vapor xcode?

Comment: I've had issues in the past with static file communication between Safari and Vapor. In production, deploying behind nginx solves this issue. What I'm saying is, your configuration might be correct but the issue is in the framework. I didn't have the issue with other browsers, so try Firefox or Chrome to see if it's you or Vapor.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. Turns out the problem was caused by creating the initial application with Vapor version 1.1, then updating to Vapor version 1.3.

I created a new application with Vapor 1.3, and made the same changes to create my web app, then it all worked. This is a bit worrying going forward if upgrading Vapor will stop apps working...

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer because you answered your own question.